# Is there an open source C visual debugger for windows?

Tags: c, windows, debugging

Is there an open source C visual debugger for windows?
I have heard about the visual C++ express free edition, but does it have a visual debugger?

Thanks.

Comment: [windows version of the GDB frontend DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574456/995714), [Something similar to DDD debugger for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7532/3579), https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging,

Answer (score 7):

It's not open source (but then does it really need to be?) [Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) is an IDE with an integrated debugger.

You can create a C++ project, delete the .cpp files and create/include your .c files.

Comment: is VC++ express better or Eclipse CDT?

Comment: There are a few limitations in the Express Edition debugger compared to the full edition.  The one I often miss is the built-in hex file viewer.   I think some of the multithread debugging menus are missing also.

Answer (score 5):

[Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is a good alternative. It also has some nifty features such as refactoring and a preprocessor macro explorer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a claim that the [DDD debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) will run on Windows under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  I've used DDD quite a bit and like it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [CodeLite](http://codelite.org/) IDE. I could attach to gdb debbager and provide GUI for it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is the standard for windows development. I have never seen a better IDE for this platform (or any other for that matter).

If has a debugger integrated in the IDE.  Try it - you'll probably like it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Insight](http://sources.redhat.com/insight/) that is a graphical frontend to GDB in conjunction with mingw (gcc).

You can also use [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) that has an integrated debugger interface (I only tried it with gcc/gdb but it should work with other compilers/debuggers).

If you don't mind them not being Open Source (but just free to use) you can have a look at "[Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/index.htm)" (for Windows and Windows Mobile) and "[lcc-win32](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/)" both based on the [lcc](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/) compiler.

Of course, the already suggested [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) from Microsoft will work perfectly on Windows.