# windows version of the GDB frontend DDD

Tags: windows, user-interface, gdb, ddd-debugger

Is there a native (not cygwin) version of [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) available for download somewhere?

Comment: See also https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7532/something-similar-to-ddd-debugger-for-windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is also a GDB front-end for MS Visual Studio, called [WinGDB](http://www.wingdb.com). It supports both Cygwin and MinGW. You use it just like built-in debugger in VS. It's also possible to debug remotely on Linux via SSH.

Comment: Just curios as to why this was accepted as the answer? It does not explain how to run DDD under Windows  (GDB != DDD).  I am still looking for any other Windows debugger that san chow me something like this http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/all.png

Comment: For anyone randomly stumbling across this after all these years. Microsoft now actually has its own GDB bridge for Visual Studio 2015. You can get it here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35dbae07-8c1a-4f9d-94b7-bac16cad9c01 . It's based around this Open-Source project: https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine . It worked for a MSYS2 based makefile project for me.

Answer (score 13):

DDD has not been ported to Windows AFAIK. But there ARE native gdb, which can be perfectly built using MingW32.
You can also build [Insight](http://sourceware.org/insight/faq.php) natively using Mingw32.
You can also give a try to [BeaverDbg](http://code.google.com/p/beaverdbg/)

Comment: I have just tried beaver and it launched my process OK, but break-pointing caused it to crash which left me reaching for the add/remove programs option pretty fast.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Affinic Debugger GUI](http://www.affinic.com). It is a native Windows application and is similar to DDD. It uses GDB as the backend.

Comment: Affinic recently reached version 1.0, and is now only free for a 30-day trial.

Comment: It doesn't show linked data structures graphically, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-platform gdb frontend, Qt Creator comes to mind. It also does "native" cdb on Windows, but I am not sure that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score -19):

Since there is no native windows (not cygwin) gdb, there can't be a native windows (not cygwin) ddd.