# How do I use the MinGW gdb debugger to debug a C++ program in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb, mingw

I have looked for documentation on this and found nothing. I have MinGW installed and it works great. I just don't know how to use the debugger.

Given some simple code, say in a file called "mycode.cpp":

```
int main()
{
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        temp += i;

    return 0;
}
```

...how would I debug this. What are the commands that I use to debug code with MinGW and GDB in windows? Can I step through the code via the command line like in Visual Studio? If so what commands do I use to do that?

Are there any tutorials for using GDB out there? I couldn't find any, but if anyone could direct me to one that would be great too. I'm tired of writing tons of `std::cout` statements to debug complex code.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The first step is to compile your program with `-g` to include debugging information within the executable:

```
g++ -g -o myprog.exe mycode.cpp
```

Then the program can be loaded into `gdb`:

```
gdb myprog.exe
```

A few commands to get you started:

- `break main` will cause the debugger to break when `main` is called. You can also break on lines of code with `break FILENAME:LINENO`. For example, `break mycode.cpp:4` breaks execution whenever the program reaches line 4 of `mycode.cpp`.
- `start` starts the program. In your case, you need to set breakpoints before starting the program because it exits quickly.

At a breakpoint:

- `print VARNAME`. That's how you print values of variables, whether local, static, or global. For example, at the `for` loop, you can type `print temp` to print out the value of the `temp` variable.
- `step` This is equivalent to "step into".
- `next` or `adv +1` Advance to the next line (like "step over"). You can also advance to a specific line of a specific file with, for example, `adv mycode.cpp:8`.
- `bt` Print a backtrace. This is a stack trace, essentially.
- `continue` Exactly like a "continue" operation of a visual debugger. It causes the program execution to continue until the next break point or the program exits.

The best thing to read is the [GDB users' manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: A few more commands you should be familiar with:  `run`, `continue`, `next`, `list` and `help`.  When all else fails, try using `help`.

Comment: tried `g++ -g helloworld.c`, it generated only a.exe. Is it supposed to generate some more files to help debugging with gdb. Running `gdb a.exe` gives message:`not in executable format: File format not recognized` and starts `(gdb)` command prompt.  Running `(gdb) break main` gives `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`. Running `(gdb) start` gives the same `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: @Mahesha999 No other files are generated; the debugging information is stored within the executable. Can you try running `a.exe` directly? "not in executable format: File format not recognized" implies that `a.exe` is not an executable.

Comment: @Mahesha999 What target is listed in the "This GDB was configured as ..." message when you start `gdb` (if you don't see such a message, what is the output of the `show configuration` command)? Maybe `a.exe` is 64-bit and `gdb` is configured for 32-bit, or vice versa?

Comment: I asked related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717962/setting-up-vscode-for-c-c-debugging-on-window-7-with-gcc-g-and-gdb). I am using gdb, gcc, g++ from mingw distribution. **(1)** gdb is configured as "i686-pc-mingw32" **(2)** gcc.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev201506, mingwpy build) 4.9.2 **(3)** g++.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev201506, mingwpy build) 4.9.2. Also a.exe is generated from the same gcc. How do I know whether a.exe is 64bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Thank you for these details. My guess is that because your compiler is 64-bit, it is generating 64-bit binaries (unless you somehow have a cross-compiler). You can try compiling your program using the `-m32` GCC compiler option. As for checking whether an exe is 32-bit or 64-bit, there are a lot of methods listed here: https://superuser.com/q/358434/40712 Personally, I open the binary in the 32-bit and 64-bit builds of [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com) ([one of the answers](https://superuser.com/a/1088914/40712) discusses this technique).

Comment: `gcc -m32 helloworld.c` gave errors like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304804). The [comment there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18420336/1317018) explains it with `-m32` option. It asks to add `i686-w64-mingw32`/`x86_64-w64-mingw32` flags while compiling. `gcc -x86_64-w64-mingw32 helloworld.c` gives `language not recognized` error, `gcc -i686-w64-mingw32 helloworld.c` gives ` unrecognized command line option`, Am I missing some environment path variable?

Comment: @Mahesha999 If your compiler supported building 32-bit binaries in addition to 64-bit binaries, then `-m32` would be all that you need. However, as one of the answers to the question which you linked to says, the MinGW-w64 compilers appear to be single-target (that is, they only support outputting 64-bit binaries). To resolve the problem, you should either use a gdb targeting x86_64 or use gcc/g++ targeting i686 or earlier.

Comment: Should I install the desired gdb/gcc/g++ explicitly? I feel I have pretty much exhausted with the efforts to fix this thing. (Anyways billion thanks for your replies) I wish there is some article explaining everything about mingw, gcc, g++ that will help me do setup in one go instead of tweaking things one by one to check what works. I know there are many articles explaining what is what but I need something concise that will leave me with precise understanding so that I can get the setup done in single try. Or may be I simply lack experience to assimilate the things...

Comment: @Mahesha999 "Should I install the desired gdb/gcc/g++ explicitly?" That's what I would do. Just use matching gdb and gcc/g++; i.e. either both are 32-bit or both are 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few gdb guis for windows in this question [windows version of the GDB frontend DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574456/windows-version-of-the-gdb-frontend-ddd)

Although DDD hasn't been ported