# "Dual-target" MinGW-w64 isn't really dual-target?

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

When I try to compile a 32-bit program on a 64-bit host with [MinGW-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/64-bit/threads-win32/seh/):

```
T:\mingw64>.\bin\g++ -m32 Test.cpp
```

I get:

```
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0\libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgcc_s.a when searching for -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
t:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Similarly when I try to compile a 64-bit program on a 32-bit host with [MinGW-builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-win32/dwarf/):

```
T:\mingw32>.\bin\g++ -m64 Test.cpp
```

I get:

```
Test.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
 #include <iostream>
 ^
```

Aren't [MinGW-builds supposed to be dual-target](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/GeneralUsageInstructions)?

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the only dual-target MinGW-w64 build is [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/start). All variants of MinGW Builds seem to be single-target, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Haroogan: Doesn't MinGW-builds claim to be dual-target though?

Comment: Well, yeah, according to this page it seems like they do. But the output you get is suspicious. Have you checked whether the distribution actually contains all these libraries in both variants (32-bit and 64-bit)?

Comment: @Haroogan: To be honest I never understand how the library-finding system in GCC works... it seems to only look for libraries in folders it's been hardcoded to look in, so even if I copy over libraries into a different architecture folder from another GCC it never seems to work. I just end up getting confused at what's going on, what's included and what isn't, hence the question. According to the error the libs don't exist but I haven't checked further.

Comment: Did you download SEH variant?

Comment: @Haroogan: Yes, that's also the one I linked to.

Comment: So, I can tell you that it's the single-target one. It was also confirmed on the mailing list recently.

Comment: @Haroogan: Huh... do you know which ones are multitarget?

Comment: The plain old SJLJ should be for sure.

Comment: @Haroogan: The 32-bit SJLJ indeed does compile for both architectures, but when I try to run its 64-bit output, it says `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.` Its 32-bit output runs fine.

Comment: `0xC000007B` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` and this is a good evidence that the 64-bit application is trying to load 32-bit DLL. Check it with Dependency Walker, and also make sure whether you have 64-bit DLLs in the `PATH`.

Comment: @Haroogan: Ahh that explains it! I needed to have `\i686-w64-mingw32\lib64` in my path, but it was looking inside `\bin`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, want to see all this in the form of summarized answer?

Comment: @Haroogan: Definitely, sounds great! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the **[General Usage Instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/GeneralUsageInstructions)** page on MinGW-w64 Wiki claims that the **[MinGW-builds](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)** project supplies dual-target compilers, this is not completely true anymore. The SEH variants (which come starting from GCC 4.8.0) are only single-target. You can see it yourself by inspecting the directory structure of their distributions, i.e. they contain only the libraries with either 64- or 32-bit addressing, but not both. Furthermore, recently it was confirmed on the mailing list of MinGW-builds.

On the other hand, plain old SJLJ distributions are indeed dual-target. If you get:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).
>   Click OK to close the application.

when running the 64-bit application produced by these distributions, then you should recall that `0xC000007B` is the code of `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`, which is a good evidence that 64-bit application is trying to load 32-bit DLLs. Probably, you have added `\bin` to `PATH`, whereas should have added `\i686-w64-mingw32\lib64` for 64-bit applications to run properly.

Comment: So it's not possible to have the `bin` directory in the `Path` environment variable when cross-compiling? That's a pretty big limitation I think... Who always wants to use absolute paths to `g++` etc.?

Answer (score 7):

For those who are getting this linker error on **linux** with mingw, you are probably trying to build a 32 bit binary with the 64 bit compiler with the -m32 flag or the other way around it.

To fix this issue, just compile with `i686-w64-mingw32` instead of `x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Comment: This did it for me, Thanks! I added -i686-w64-mingw32 flag to g++ flags.

Comment: `gcc -x86_64-w64-mingw32 helloworld.c` gave language not recognized error, `gcc -i686-w64-mingw32 helloworld.c` gavea ` unrecognized command line option`. I am using gdb, gcc, g++ from mingw distribution on Windows 7 64 bit. **(1)** gdb is configured as "i686-pc-mingw32" **(2)** gcc.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev201506, mingwpy build) 4.9.2 **(3)** g++.exe (x86_64-win32-seh-rev201506, mingwpy build) 4.9.2.