# Code Blocks debugger fails with program arguments

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, command-line-arguments, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 (with MinGW), and when I want to start a debugging session after setting program arguments, the GDB debugger just stop executing at the very beginning and the whole program freezes. It freaks me out, because I cannot debug my programs which need command line arguments. These are the last two lines in the "Debugger" window (after this nothing happens, Code::Blocks freezes):

```
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
```

Does anyone know the reason, why GDB does not work with command line arguments?

Comment: GDB *does* work with command line arguments.  Can you show a log of what GDB commands your IDE is actually running?

Comment: Uhmm, where can I find this log? I found a "Debugger initialization commands" box in debugger settings, but it is empty, I dont know is that what you were talking about...

Actually it sometimes works, sometimes freezes (with the same arguments!), just like there is a bug in Code::Blocks/GDB which sometimes comes up and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Code::Blocks.

Comment: Hopefully by now you have looked ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671900/how-do-i-use-the-mingw-gdb-debugger-to-debug-a-c-program-in-windows)***.  This was just a simple google search :)

Answer (score 0):

Update CodeBlocks and GDB.
It might be bugs and updating codeblocks is worth it because bugs have been solved.