# can i install GNU DDD into Windows 7 OS?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gnu

I heard that there is a graphical debugger by GNU called DDD, which will help to learn C. I have searched DDD for windows 7, but i won't get anything useful. All i saw is DDD on Linux. My question is can i install DDD into Windows 7 ? if so where can i find set up file and other information ?

Comment: use cygwin in Windows. You will get ddd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574456/windows-version-of-the-gdb-frontend-ddd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, because you're learning C try to resist the temptation to depend entirely on your debugger to figure out what's wrong with your code.  A debugger **assists** the brain but shouldn't replace it.

That being said, it might be less ambitious to start with a free IDE+toolchain with a decent debugger that's a bit easier to get up and running than Cygwin & friends.

I've always liked the now opensourced [Watcom C](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) toolchain a lot, and it comes with a nice debugger.  It's showing its age a bit, but it's still a very capable tool.

Microsoft still offers its [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng#products/visual-studio-express-products) "lite" version of VS for free.  Aside from some restrictions, it's a Visual Studio 2012.

And of course there are the IDE's built mostly around gcc, like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [many others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B)

Comment: Am not using it for the purpose of coding. I just want to c memory map,register content etc..

Comment: @MSharathHegde that doesn't invalidate my recommendation.  Any good debugger offers all that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it installing  [Cygwin](http://x.cygwin.com/). In this way you can use all the linux GNU Tools under Windows.

> Cygwin is a Unix-like environment and
>   command-line interface for Microsoft Windows. Cygwin provides native
>   integration of Windows-based applications, data, and other system
>   resources with applications, software tools, and data of the Unix-like
>   environment. Thus it is possible to launch Windows applications from
>   the Cygwin environment, as well as to use Cygwin tools and
>   applications within the Windows operating context.

Here's the [Cygwin installation guide](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html#setup-cygwin-x-installing).

Comment: Do i need to install  Cygwin/X setup ?

Comment: Note that to get ddd running you'll also need X, and Cygwin's X is not the easiest piece of software to get running properly.

Comment: @Atropo how can i invoke ddd ?

Comment: You should start cygwin, then start the X server the command should be `startx` and then launch the `ddd` command