# Is there an open source C visual debugger for Window OS?

Tags: c, debugging

When I find a question which another person asked before, there wasn't answer for solution about debugger for window OS.

So I ask it again.

Also I wanna make a program can debug and can show memory structure, allocation, leak in GUI.

So let me know about that source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an open source C visual debugger for windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431000/is-there-an-open-source-c-visual-debugger-for-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an open source C visual debugger for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431000/is-there-an-open-source-c-visual-debugger-for-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html)

Comment: Hmm. thx but Is that project opensource?

And also I would like to ask ,, is there any project can show memory struct as Graphic not with just only words like Visual studio series